# What is the quickest way to write out a large data frame as json in R?

Tags: json, r

I need to write a large data frame to a file as JSON in R. I am using the rjson package. The approach below is quite slow...

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      write.table(toJSON(df[i,]),"[FILENAME]",
      row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,append=TRUE)
    }
```

So I tried this:

```
write.table(toJSON(df),"FILENAME]",
            row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Which chokes because toJSON() cannot handle a string that is of very long length. So I would like to perhaps write out chunks of my data table at a time. What is the recommended approach for this? If it involves `split()` could you provide some psuedocode?

Comment: What package are you using here? `rjson`?

Comment: yes, should have mentioned that, rjson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a big(ger) data set

```
big = iris[rep(seq_len(nrow(iris)), 1000),]
```

the for loop with `toJSON(df[i,])` creates a flat file of key-value pairs representing each row, whereas `toJSON(df)` produces column vectors; these are very different. We aim for the equivalent of `toJSON(df[i,])`, but formatted as a single JSON string.

Start by munging `big` into a list-of-lists `lol` with each inner element named (making the factor into a character, so as not to confuse json further down), so `lol` looks like `list(big[1,], big[2,], ...)` but with names on each element.

```
big1 <- Map(function(x, nm) setNames(x, rep(nm, length(x))), big, names(big))
big1$Species <- as.character(big1$Species)
lol <- unname(do.call(Map, c(list, big1)))
```

Then we turn it into a vector-of-json, using the rjson library and `splitIndices` provided by the parallel library (probably other ways of generating the split)

```
chunks <- 10
json <- sapply(splitIndices(length(lol), chunks), function(idx) toJSON(lol[idx]))
```

We could almost write the json chunks to file, but they aren't quite legitimate -- all but the last string should end with ",", but end with a "]", and all but the first should start with nothing, but instead start with "[".

```
substring(json[-length(json)], nchar(json)[-length(json)]) = ","
substring(json[-1], 1, 1) = ""
```

These are then ready to be written to file

```
fl <- tempfile()
writeLines(json, fl)
```

Combining, and certainly many special cases for column type coercion are un-handled,

```
library(parallel)  ## just for splitIndices; no parallel processing here...
library(json)
fastJson <- function(df, fl, chunks=10) {
    df1 = Map(function(x, nm) setNames(x, rep(nm, length(x))), df, names(df))
    df1 <- lapply(df1, function(x) {
        if (is(x, "factor")) as.character(x) else x
    })
    lol = unname(do.call(Map, c(list, df1)))

    idx <- splitIndices(length(lol), chunks)
    json <- sapply(idx, function(i) toJSON(lol[i]))
    substring(json[-length(json)], nchar(json)[-length(json)]) <- ","
    substring(json[-1], 1, 1) <- ""
    writeLines(json, fl)
}
```

With

```
> fastJson(big, tempfile())
> system.time(fastJson(big, fl <- tempfile()))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.340   0.008   2.352 
 > system(sprintf("wc %s", fl))
     10      10 14458011 /tmp/RtmpjLEh5h/file3fa75d00a57c
```

In contrast, just sub-setting big (without any parsing to JSON or writing to a file) takes a long time:

```
> system.time(for (i in seq_len(nrow(big))) big[i,])
   user  system elapsed 
 57.632   0.088  57.835
```

Opening this file to append, once for each row, does not take much time compared to sub-setting

```
> system.time(for (i in seq_len(nrow(big))) { con <- file(fl, "a"); close(con) })
   user  system elapsed 
  2.320   0.580   2.919
```

Answer (score 1):

What is extremely slow with your first approach is that every time you call `write.table` the file is opened, the handle moved to the bottom of the file, data written, then the file is closed. It will be much faster if you open the file only once and use a file handle. Like this:

```
fh <- file("[FILENAME]", "w")
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    write.table(toJSON(df[i,]), fh,
                row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
}
close(fh)
```

I also removed the `append = TRUE` as it is implied (hence not necessary) when using a file connection.

Comment: Timing? For me  with `big = iris[rep(seq_len(nrow(iris)), 100),]` I have `for (i in seq_len(nrow(big))) toJSON(big[i,])` taking 3s, appending to file 12.6s, appending to open connection 11s. Also worth noting that `toJSON(df[i,])` (rows) produces different JSON from `toJSON(df)` (column vectors).

Comment: @Morgan, I guess that's too small a test to start seeing a real difference. When using a file connection, processing each row will take the same amount of time. While with the OP's method, each row will take longer and longer to move the filehandle to the end of the file. To start seeing a difference though, the file needs to be big enough that moving the filehandle becomes significant with regards to the other operations in the loop. But I have to admit I am somewhat surprised that the repetitive opening/closing does not make more of a difference, even with a small example.