# Fast delimited JSON writing with arrow?

Tags: r, apache-arrow

Is it possible to use the R arrow package to write JSON-LD? I know there are very fast methods to write CSV (`arrow::write_csv_arrow`) and parquet, and I have been using `arrow::read_json_arrow` for super fast reading of very large delimited JSON.

But to write I am still using `writeLines` which seems fairly slow. I wonder if there are plans to support this in arrow itself?

Thanks

Updated with reproducible example showing my current code. In reality the data is much larger and the JSON generation takes over 1 hour:

```r
library(data.table)
library(arrow)
library(rbenchmark)

dt <- data.table(id = 1:1000)
for (i in seq(3)) dt[[paste0("numeric",i)]] <- runif(nrow(dt))
for (i in seq(4)) dt[[paste0("symbolic",i)]] <- as.character(paste0("X",round(1000*runif(nrow(dt)))))

listToJson <- function(l) {
  jsonlite::toJSON(l, auto_unbox = T, na = "null", digits = NA)
}

b <- benchmark( "row-wise json" = {
  writeLines(sapply(seq(nrow(dt)), function(r) { listToJson(as.list(dt[r,])) }), "test.json")
},
"write.csv" = {
  write.csv(dt, "test.csv")
},
"arrow::write_csv_arrow" = {
  arrow::write_csv_arrow(dt, "test.csv")
},
replications = 10
)
```

Results show how much slower my JSON writing is compared to CSV, even with `write.csv`:

| test | replications | elapsed | relative | user.self | sys.self | user.child | sys.child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arrow::write_csv_arrow | 10 | 0.029 | 1.000 | 0.027 | 0.004 | 0 | 0 |
| write.csv | 10 | 0.054 | 1.862 | 0.051 | 0.004 | 0 | 0 |
| row-wise json | 10 | 5.056 | 174.345 | 5.014 | 0.040 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to do this with the R package (or the underlying C++ implementation).  There is a [ticket open on the project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5033) which mentions this, but it has not been worked on. I have added a comment on there highlighting that it would be useful to have.

In the meantime, perhaps if you tell us a bit more about your code and data (how many rows/columns etc, the code you're using to write it), we could see if there's anything we can do to help make it it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently just applying jsonlite::toJSON on all rows of my table. The table has many columns and I don't know in advance which ones, so sprintf seems not feasible. Writing LDJSON this way is orders of magnitude slower than CSV. If you know a better way, I'd be glad to learn. I'll update my post to show exactly what I did.

Comment: Thanks for your reproducible example there.  I think the slowdown you experience is less about `writeLines()` and more in how the data is being converted to JSON - as you're iterating across each row.

There's a similar question here with a response which shows how to speed things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907003/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-write-out-a-large-data-frame-as-json-in-r

Comment: I believe you are right. I have tried a few different improvements. The fastest seems to be to just have `jsonlite` convert the whole frame into a big regular JSON string `jsonlite::toJSON(dt, digits = NA)` then post-process the string to make it multi-line JSON. This approaches the speed of `write.csv` (but `arrow::write_csv_arrow`) is still much faster so I guess my original request still stand.